# Change equation using beamer without reformatting slide

Tags: beamer, equations

I am writing a presentation in beamer and I want to add a box round an equation and then change the equation. The code below does this:

```
\begin{frame}{Fishing mortality $F$}
\onslide<2->{
Fishing mortality is
\begin{equation*}
F_{a,t} = \sum_{f}F_{f,a,t}
\end{equation*}
where $F_{f,a,t}$ is the fishing mortality of the $f$th fleet at time $t$ on age $a$,
}

\only<3>{
\begin{equation*}
F_{f,a,t}=\text{effort}_{f,t}\times \text{selectivity}_{f,a}\times\text{catchability}_{f,a}.
\label{eq1}
\end{equation*}
}
\only<4>{
\begin{equation*}
F_{f,a,t}=\text{effort}_{f,t}\times \boxed{ \text{selectivity}_{f,a}\times\text{catchability}_{f,a}}.
\label{eq2}
\end{equation*}
}

\onslide<5->{
\begin{equation*}
F_{f,a,t}=\text{effort}_{f,t}\times \text{gear}_{f,a}}\onslide<6->{\times\text{year}_{f,t}.}
\label{eq3}
\end{equation*}


\end{frame}
```

However, the formatting of the whole slide changes when `eq1`, `eq2` and `eq3` are added or removed to the screen. Changing `\only` to `\visible` keeps the formatting the same but the three equations are one above the other.

What I want is the part in `\onslide<2->` to be in the same location throughout the slide; `F_{f,a,t}=\text{effort}_{f,t}\times` to be in the same location when all three equations are added; `\text{selectivity}_{f,a}\times\text{catchability}_{f,a}.` to be in the same location when `eq1` and `eq2` are shown and  `\text{gear}_{f,a}}\onslide<6->{\times\text{year}_{f,t}.` to appear next to `F_{f,a,t}=\text{effort}_{f,t}\times`.

Can anyone help?

Cheers
Mike

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Does it help to top-align the frame's contents, by changing `\begin{frame}{...}` to `\begin{frame}[t]{...}`?

Answer (score 1):

- An easy way to avoid vertical shifts in your frame is to use a `[t]`op aligned frame
- to avoid horizontal jumping from adding the box around your formula, you could already draw it in the previous slide, but in the same colour as the background
- to avoid horizontal jumping from replacing the terms in your formula, you could left align the whole equation

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Fishing mortality $F$}
\onslide<2->{
Fishing mortality is
\begin{equation*}
F_{a,t} = \sum_{f}F_{f,a,t}
\end{equation*}
where $F_{f,a,t}$ is the fishing mortality of the $f$th fleet at time $t$ on age $a$,
}

\begin{flalign*}
\only<3->{F_{f,a,t}=\text{effort}_{f,t}\times}
\only<4>{\color{red}}%
\only<3>{\color{white}}%
\only<3-4>{\boxed{\color{black} \text{selectivity}_{f,a}\times\text{catchability}_{f,a}}.}
\only<5->{\text{gear}_{f,a}}
\only<6->{\times\text{year}_{f,t}.}&&
\end{flalign*}

\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]